# Thermal expansion nee contraction: installing subfloor in unfinished attic

Tags: flooring, attic, temperature

I am working in an unfinished attic where the temperature exceeds 100F in Summer (now), and that will be stabilized to more normal temperatures once finished.

I need to install the subfloor to be able to work on the rest of the project safely, but I am concerned about shrinkage once things cool down to a more reasonable level.

Should I leave the customary 1/8" between floorboards? Less? Do Something else?

Comment: What is the temperature & humidity like where the boards are currently stored (and acclimated)?

Comment: The boards were acclimated for several days in the attic itself. They match the surrounding environment's condition.